# MSIE can turn on autocorrect — which is confusing!

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Title was: *Please turn off autocorrect entirely if a line begins with four spaces.*

My morning so far.

`space space space space p [ i ]` oops it autocorrected to `p[I]`, so `backspace backspace i ]` dammit it did it again `CTRL-Z` What the heck *CTRL-Z does not undo autoformatting as is right and just!!!*  Forget it, I'll use `j`.

So, three feature requests.

1. Turn off autoformatting *entirely* if a line begins with four spaces.
2. Immediately after an autoformatting, any use of backspace should temporarily turn off autoformatting. The user is backspacing because they didn't like your decision. Don't repeat it.
3. CTRL-Z should undo the last action.  **Autoformatting is an action**.

UPDATE: Apparently some people are having difficulty reproducing this.  I am typing answers to C questions in StackOverflow, specifically: [How to assign a pointer to another pointer of different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705170/how-to-assign-a-pointer-to-another-pointer-of-different-type/20707597#20707597)

I'm at my desktop machine using IE 10 as the browser.

UPDATE: Doesn't repro on Chrome. Good heavens, is IE doing this to me???

UPDATE: AAARGH IE 10 turned on spelling autocorrection by default.

OK SO, this one is on Microsoft, not on you. Microsoft should know better than to make CTRL-Z work differently in VS, Word and IE. I will send them a sternly worded letter.

Sorry for the spam. I'll self-answer this one so that the next time someone is tricked by this, they'll hopefully find me looking foolish. :-)

Comment: Is autoformatting a thing? Where does this happen?

Comment: Are we talking about mobile? My desktop certainly doesn't do this.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Start writing an answer on StackOverflow and see what happens when you type what I typed.

Comment: @EricLippert Yeah I tried it, this has never happened for me.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName: I'm sitting at my desk right now.

Comment: I can't reproduce on SO. What browser are you using?

Comment: @EricLippert Could this be a user script of some sort?

Comment: Regarding update, even on the same question, same browser, I can't repro. I... don't think this is an SO thing.

Comment: Reproduced using IE 11 on [so] and here on Meta, not with Chrome.

Comment: Does your browser look something like [this](http://imgur.com/Y19APV1)? If it does, that could be the problem.

Comment: It's IE. It's a feature. It's to force you to paste code from VS or notepad instead of composing in place :-)

Comment: _"...this one is on Microsoft"_ It's **always** on Microsoft.

Comment: Good luck with your sternly-worded letter.

Comment: This question will make a great resource to give to people suffering from [impostor syndrome](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ImAPhonyAreYou.aspx)... If Eric Lippert can ask a dumb question, there's hope for us all!

Comment: At least it wasn't localization.

Comment: @AakashM: There are no dumb questions, only dumb people. And no dumb people use Stack Overflow. (Of course *ignorant* people use SO all the time.)

Comment: Should probably be taggeed with [support] rather than [feature-request]--unless it's possible to specify in HTML that autocorrection will be disabled on a particular input element or page.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: You may want to look up Eric's career history. If anyone on Stack Overflow has a chance to be heard on this issue, I'd have Eric at the top of that list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I haven't worked with the IE team since 2001; what limited pull I ever had there is long gone now.

Comment: @EricLippert: but on a scale of 'likelyhood to be listened to' from 1 to 100 I know where, relatively speaking, you, ThisSuitISBlackNot, and I lie. :-)

Comment: [ insert generic MSIE insult here ]

Answer (score 26):

Autocorrect of `i` to `I` is a feature of Internet Explorer 10 which is turned on by default.

To turn it off, go to the `Tool` icon, then `Manage add-Ons`, then click `Spelling Correction` and then uncheck the `Enable spelling correction` checkbox that appears.

Comment: Enjoy another 10 imaginary points.  Props for hunting down the issue.