# Capital letters when writing questions/answers and comments

Tags: support, questions, comments, answers

I have the following issue. When i write a question/answer/comment the first letters of some words like "need" automaticaly begin with capital letters. I noticed that many of my posts get edited cause of this. Look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21142434/revisions). Note the "Need" and "Show". Why does this happen?

EDIT: if i write Change without pressing shift it writes Change with capital "C". It happened also to the word show as you see in the example link. But since i corrected it manualy it don't happen anymore.
It is not a big issue just wanted to know if it happens only to me or also to others.
Thanks

Comment: A browser extension perhaps?

Comment: I don't think so, because at home i am using opera and right now i am with iexplore 11. I also don't notice this behavior on any other page...

Comment: Can you add an example? *When I type `foo bar baz`, after posting it has changed to `foo Bar baz`.*

Comment: I didn't notice this ever. According to @Stijn may be your browser's issue.

Comment: Could be... But then shouldn't this happen also on other Websites?

Comment: @Stijn it don't happen after posting, but immediately after finishing the word by pressing space.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212938/msie-can-turn-on-autocorrect-which-is-confusing relevant?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/663772/how-do-i-disable-spell-checking-in-ie-11-win-8-1
It is a win8 issue which i can only turn using regedit :P +1 for Microsoft. I can't answer my question cause i am new so if someone wants to do that for me i can mark it as solved.

Comment: Oh good grief, what an annoying thing to encounter. You should be able to self-answer soon, just check back in a bit (the system should tell you how long you have left to wait).

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours cause i have 9 instead of 10 reputation xD

Comment: @Springrbua Problem solved

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now i have to wait 2 days to be able to accept it xD

Comment: @Springrbua Sadly I can't help you with that one :p

Comment: @RichardTingle true, but we can nudge him when the time comes. ;)

Comment: I think i will accept it after weekend. But it is a good idea to nudge me xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for reporting that here. It is not a stackexchange thing but a microsoft thing. The internet explorer has a spelling correction, which can be turned off ([MSIE can turn on autocorrect — which is confusing!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212938/msie-can-turn-on-autocorrect-which-is-confusing)) if you are not using win8. If you are using win 8 you have to do it with regedit ([How do I disable spell checking in IE 11 (Win 8.1)?](https://superuser.com/questions/663772/how-do-i-disable-spell-checking-in-ie-11-win-8-1)).
Thanks to everybody

Comment: Don't be sorry, this can help others with the same issue. Cheers!